# How to check for succes/error for a API post in React Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, http, react-redux

I have a form on the page and on filling up the fields, i click submit. It makes a Post API call to the backend. I also expect some response from the API call. I am trying to figure out how to differentiate between a success response and an error response.

for e.g. For success, i get the following response.

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      //These are the fields and i display the field values on the page
      "age": 32,
      "sex": 'male'
    }
  }
}
```

In case there is a failure on the API call being made, i get below response

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": "401",
      "title": "Unauthorized request"
    }
  ]
}
```

Even if there are any other failure reasons, for e.g. `Unauthorized access` or `Internal server error`, i will be getting its respective "status" and "title" in the `errors` array as shown above.

How can i differentiate if the response is a success or failure and if it is a failure, how do i check for which failure status is being returned. Can someone please help in understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add 2 more actions - one for Success and the other one for Fail.

In Saga function*, add try-catch block.
In try, after Api post call command, you can request success action.
In catch, you can request fail action.

```
try {
  const result = yield call(axios.POST, ....) // API Post call
  yield put(actions.successAction(result))
} catch(error) {
  yield put(actions.failAction(error))
}
```

Comment: i get this part. i am not getting the part where i can figure out if the response was success or it was failure response

Comment: Is it that all API call which is a success executes in try block and alll failures in API call would go to catch block ?

Comment: correct. success api call will be in try, and failure will be in catch.